# why i am getting ? along with query parameters in laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel, get, request, query-string

I am sending request via query parameters in laravel but this error is very uncommon to me as i have never seen this before what it actually does is it adds ?in very first key like this

```
array:1 [▼
  "?name" => "google"
]
```

while hitting this url

```
http://travel.localhost/home?name=google
```

```
        dd($_GET);
        dd(request()->all());
        dd(request()-get('name'));
```

i have done all these method but for first two lines i am getting
?name =

and for third line i am getting null as i am looking for name but request is ?name

as per my knowledge we use GET request frequently and bind required parameters in query parameter like ?param1=&param2=&param3 ... and so on

so please anyone having any idea why this error occured or is anything wrong in my project

is this can be related to server as i am doing this on nginx but when i am using serve method

and serving my  project on localhost:8000 then this problem is not there

any help

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution found on this link https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/get-request-includes-question-mark-as-part-of-parameter-name?reply=448658

---

To get request paramters either its POST or GET use the `request()` helper for it.

Example:
URL: `http://travel.localhost/home?name=google`

Use `request()->get('name');` Result will be `google` this can be used for post parameters as well.

If you want to get all the request paramters
Use `request()->all()` Result will be

```php
[
   'name' => 'google'
]
```

Also check your `app\Http\Kernel.php` file and see if you're missing any middleware mentioned in below picture.
[image]

Comment: i am doing the same and then i got ?name= this is pretty weird as i have never encountered this before

Comment: @RohanSingh check by updated answer.

Comment: no this is very fresh project and i have seen one more thing  that i have 2 projects and both  projects give me this error while getting query string data ? is added on first key but when i am doing php artisan serve and hitting that url without changing any thing i am getting what i have desired

Comment: @RohanSingh  check this url 
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/get-request-includes-question-mark-as-part-of-parameter-name?reply=448658 
Maybe this is the issue

Comment: Thanks sir for your help exactly this was my problem as i was aware that this problem was from nginx configuration . A big thanks to you

Comment: @RohanSingh No Problem, Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Because get method pass parameter like that try using post method

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to it is consider ? as a special char. If you could try below link?
http://travel.localhost/home?act=1&name=google